# How to hide / remove wpdotnet logo?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, wordpress

I'm experimenting with Wordpress on .NET (wpdotnet), and so far I was able to create a first project, but there's one thing bothering me, which is that, on every page there is the logo for the project like this:

[wpdotnet logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xei1p.png)

I tried inspecting the page, and the code for that is:

```html
<div style="position:fixed;text-align:center; width:192px; height:50px; bottom:0; right:0;padding:12px 0 12px 50px; margin:0 auto; vertical-align: middle;background:#68b227;background-image:url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iolevel/wpdotnet-sdk/master/wpdotnet.png);background-size:50px 50px;background-repeat:no-repeat;border-left:solid 10px rgba(255,255,255,.5);line-height:24px;" title="WpDotNet">
    <a href="https://www.wpdotnet.com/?from=footer" style="color:#fff;font-size:16px;font-style:tahoma,helvetica;padding:0; margin:0;">WpDotNet</a>
</div>
```

There's no class neither an id for this div and I cannot find the source (by this, I mean the file where this code is written) for this html. How can I remove this from the pages?

Comment: Have you tried `.parent-selector div { background: none; }`?

Comment: You could select the element by its `title` attribute by using an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) like `[title="WpDotNet"] { display:none; }`.

Comment: @showdev this worked! Thank you so much! Can you write this as an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: @Pingu tell me please, where did you add this attribute? I faced the same problem

Comment: @МитасовЭдуард I added it to the "additional css" resource on the WordPress panel, if I remember correctly.